# how to Wrap Text across an image in docx file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, docx

I am making a docx generator using Docx.dll. So far i have been able to insert images and text into the document. The images and paragraph are not aligned. I need to wrap text the image. How do i do it?
I looked for it in google and found this link
[Adding Images to Documents in Word 2007 by Using the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee342530%28v=office.12%29.aspx). The code is working and creating the word document too, but the docx file is not opening.

How do i wrap text 'In Front Of Text' in c#?

```
public static DocX CreateDocumentFile(List<CompanyInfo> info)
    {

        DocX document = DocX.Load(@"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\RetailWrite.docx");

        foreach (var companies in info)
        {

            Formatting fm = new Formatting();

            /*Inserting Image*/
            Novacode.Image img = document.AddImage(@"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\logos\slime.png");
            Novacode.Paragraph companyLogo = document.InsertParagraph("");
            Picture pic1 = img.CreatePicture();
            companyLogo.InsertPicture(pic1, 0);


            Novacode.Paragraph CompanyName = document.InsertParagraph(companies.Name.ToString());
            CompanyName.StyleName = "COMPANY";


            Novacode.Paragraph CompanyPosition = document.InsertParagraph(companies.Position.ToString());
            CompanyPosition.StyleName = "posit";


            Novacode.Paragraph CompanyDescription = document.InsertParagraph(companies.Description.ToString());
            CompanyDescription.StyleName = "descrip";

            Novacode.Paragraph blankPara = document.InsertParagraph(" ");
            Novacode.Paragraph blankPara2 = document.InsertParagraph(" ");
        }

        return document;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post code you are working with. And Please read the FAQ , to learn how to post a question .

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem: I used the Interop of MS-Word to apply word-wrap across images.

```
public static void FormatImages()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\Temp.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath, false);

        object save_changes = false;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape item in wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                {
                    item.Select();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape = item.ConvertToShape();
                    shape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapFront;
                }
            }
        }

        doc.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\RetailWrite.docx");
        doc.Close(save_changes);
        wordApp.Quit(save_changes);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\Temp.docx"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Users\newton.sheikh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSOffice\OpenXML\OpenXML\Temp.docx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround. DocX and similar libraries are used when installing Word on the webserver is not desired.

Comment: @Sebazzz It was long time back, i was new to IT world. For me it was a "solution", it did what it was supposed to do :) but yes u r right working with Word can be a headache on server. I had big trouble when i was working on more extensions for office tools. Never did it again. May be i am not a good programmer :)